# JQuery UI, Replace and Push Down the Item Instead of Sort

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to JQuery, Trying to understand what can I do to extend the Sortable UI

What I want to achieve is:

I have a list

```
| A | B | C | . | E | F | G | H |
```

Where . is consider an empty spot.

If I drag A to B, instead of swapping places that looks like

```
| B | A | C | . | E | F | G | H |
```

- I want it to look like (A push to B (Original A spot opens), B push
  to C, C push to Open Spot)

  | . | A | B | C | E | F | G | H |
- Another example if I push B to C it becomes

  | A | . | B | C | E | F | G | H |
- Also if I were to push E to F, since to the right of H doesn't have a open slot, there should be alert saying can't move.

Here is what I have done so far, you guys can reuse

https://jsfiddle.net/tw4tzh25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
$(function() {

    var start_pos = 0;
    var start_offset = 0;

    $("#sortable").sortable({
        tolerance: "pointer",
        cancel: ".empty_spot",
        start: function(event,ui){
            start_pos = $(ui.item).index();
            start_offset =  ui.originalPosition.left;
        },
        change: function(event,ui){
            if(ui.position.left > $(ui.item).parent().find(".empty_spot").offset().left){
                alert("Can't move");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                var offset = start_pos;
                if(ui.position.left < start_offset){
                    offset += 1;
                }
                else{
                    offset += 2;
                }  

                var empty_spot = $(ui.item).parent().find(".empty_spot");
                empty_spot.insertBefore(empty_spot.siblings(':eq('+start_pos+')'));
                $("li:eq("+offset+")").insertAfter($("li:eq("+(offset+1)+")"));
                $("#sortable").sortable("refreshPositions");
            }
        }
    });

    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw4tzh25/2/). Maybe it is not perfect, but it is something :)

Comment: Wow Amazing!!! Just tested but D to Empty Slot shows Can't Move Msg, which shouldn't be the case. I think the cause is here  if(ui.position.left > $(ui.item).parent().find(".empty_spot").offset().left) in which you pretty much say the moved LI's left position is greater than Empty position then raise Msg. right?

Comment: That's right. I also didn't know how to manage movements like F to C. But feel free to take my work and fix it.